# The Density of Particle System is inverted between viewport and render

Tags: rendering, particles, hair

I am following the Donut tutorial by BlenderGuru. I have setup my particle system by weight painting the donut. The Density is set to the correct vertex group, not inverted, and the image looks great. However as soon as I try to render, and only in the render, the density of the particles inverts. It's all good in the viewport as shown in the images.

The image on the left is the rendered image and that on the right is what I see in the viewport.

[image: Rendered image]
[image: Viewport image]

How do I get them to match up. Thanks for the help.

Here is the other information in case it's useful:

[image: Menu status]
[image: Weight paint mode]

Comment: Looks like you keyframed the inversion toggle (**↔**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the "Density" entry, on the far right, there is an open diamond shape, and the <-> is orange.  This means that you have set a keyframe on density.

[image: density keyframed]

You need to clear the keyframe.  If you have a playback window, go to it and select all of the keyframes with the a key.  Then hit the x key and select "delete keyframes"

[image: Delete menu]

You can tell that this worked because the diamond and orange will disappear:

[image: no key frame]